# How to add url image in a Fragment?

Tags: android

I want to add url image in a Fragment but I am unable to do that.

```
   URL imageUrl = new URL("http://image10.bizrate-images.com/resize?sq=60&uid=2216744464");

public HomeFragment() throws MalformedURLException {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

    try {
        ImageView i = (ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.image);
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL(imageUrl).getContent());
        i.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return rootView;
}
```

It shows the error

> Error:(48, 77) error: incompatible types: URL cannot be converted to
>   String
>
> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
>
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
public HomeFragment() throws MalformedURLException {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

    try {
        URL imageUrl = new URL("http://image10.bizrate-images.com/resize?sq=60&uid=2216744464");
        ImageView i = (ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.image);
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageUrl.openConnection().getInputStream());
        i.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return rootView;
}
```

Comment: Still it is showing error while compiling :-   Error:(43, 17) error: unreported exception MalformedURLException; must be caught or declared to be thrown                                                        Error:(54, 25) error: unreported exception MalformedURLException; must be caught or declared to be thrown                                         Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Comment: @RudraKaniya i fix my code check now, hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) to load image from url.

```
Picasso.get().load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView);
```

or use [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/blob/master/README.md)

```
Glide.with(fragment).load(myUrl).into(imageView);
```